# code for inserting audio files into html without having the file in our database

Tags: html

I have written the following codes:

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px;">
      <div class="col-md-3">
           <iframe width="100%" height="160" src="https://clyp.it/owrjsttu/widget" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <iframe width="100%" height="160" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TkHWayeIT_o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
        </div>
```

But none of this gives me the freedom to share my website's link. What it does when I share, it does not provide the link for my website.
 **Can anyone please share me how to insert audio files into html PROVIDED the audio file must not be on my database.**

Answer (score 0):

This might be because cross-domain protection.

Anyway, try this:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TkHWayeIT_o?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Reference: [Youtube doc for developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player)

HTML5 have own *audio tag*, but it may not work if clyp.it is protecting the cross-domain :

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://clyp.it/owrjsttu/widget" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```